# Teach Yourself iPad Development... AppDelegate in Document Window

Tags: xcode

am reading "SAMS Teach Yourself iPad Application Development in 24 hours", in this book it got a section on tabbars (UITabBarController) where you need to link the UITabBarController component in Interface Builder to the application delegate via the Document window but in my case in XCode 4.5 (iOS 6) there is no application delegate listed in Interface Builder in Xcode... Am I doing something wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supose the book is out of date, xcode changed a lot with the 4.2 version.
I recomend you the 3rd edition of iOS Programming: big nerd ranch guide, it is updated.
Or look for an updated version of your book, if it's an ebook, they maybe send you the new version for free.